# Why my image is appearing like <img src="[object Object]" /> using NextJS 14?

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I want to use the normal `<img />` of react and not the `<Image>` component that nextjs gives you, however my images appear broken and when inspecting in the browser the src appears as "object Object", what could be happening?

```
<img className={styles.BenefitImage} src={BenefitImage} alt='Image' />
```

If I change the `<img` to `<Image` from nextjs it works... but I don't want to use the image component of nextjs...

My version of nextjs is 14.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the image as an object that you imported on the top. Try to pass as a value `BenefitImage.src`.

Well, if you don't want to use the Image component then give a chance to `next-lint` to convince you to use the Image component,

> Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth.
> Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize
> images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider.